# How to run meteor on startup on Ubuntu server

Tags: git, meteor, ubuntu-12.04

I learn meteorjs and I have a small remote VPS.

I want:

1. Set auto pulling from git repository my meteor project.
2. Put script into auto start which run my meteor project as service.

For example

```
meteor run -p 80 -- production
```

My server is Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use Ubuntu way, which is Upstart:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/init.5.html

How to define daemon job:

http://newcome.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/running-programs-as-linux-daemons-using-upstart/

Hope it helps :)

Your upstart file would be more or less:

```
# meteorjs - meteorjs job file

description "MeteorJS"
author "Igor S"

# When to start the service
start on runlevel [2345]

# When to stop the service
stop on runlevel [016]

# Automatically restart process if crashed
respawn

# Essentially lets upstart know the process will detach itself to the background
expect fork

# Run before process
pre-start script
        cd PATH_TO_METEOR_APP
        echo ""
end script

# Start the process
exec meteor run -p 80 --help -- production
```

Comment: how to run meteorite at startup with Mac OSX ?

Comment: When I run that i get "'/vagrant/.meteor' exists, but '/vagrant/.meteor/meteor' is not executable. Remove it and try again."

Comment: @MikeGraf, even better - I am trying to derive a mrt upstart from this example, but cannot seem to get it working.. any chance you could share some tips? It's really just the `exec` stanza that I can't figure out..

Comment: We had to `cwd` before executing `meteor` (so that we were in the project directory), probably have to do that with `mrt.

Comment: Sure you want to run the server as root?

Comment: For me, the stop process does not actually work properly, it remains running so I added a post script to this: post-stop script
    # clean up
    echo "Shutting down meteor & cleaning up"
    pkill -9 -f meteor
    rm -f /var/web/meteor-ratings-app/.meteor/local/db/mongod.lock
end script

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I do:

```
description "meteor app server"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn
respawn limit 10 5
pre-start script
   set -e
   rm -f /path/to/your/app/.meteor/local/db/mongod.lock
end script
exec /bin/su - ec2-user -c '/path/to/your/app/meteor_server.sh'
post-stop script
    pkill -f meteor
end script
```

The `meteor_server.sh` script contains:

```
cd /path/to/your/app/; meteor run -p 3000 --production
```

Make sure to `chmod +x` the `meteor_server.sh` script and change the path to your app in the 3 locations. The script also kills all meteor tasks when it is stopped so it works for running a single meteor app only on your server. I got a meteor app running quickly this way using nginx but node seems to consume a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1):

This is my meteorjs.conf file - works fine.
I had all described issues before, but this variant fix them.
Hope it helps somebody :)

All `EXPORT` variables I got by `printenv`

```
# meteorjs - meteorjs job file

description "MeteorJS"
author "Alex Babichev"

# When to start the service
start on runlevel [2345]

# When to stop the service
stop on runlevel [016]

# Automatically restart process if crashed
respawn

# Essentially lets upstart know the process will detach itself to the background
expect fork

chdir /home/dev/www/test

script

export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
export PWD=/home/sputnik
export NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
export HOME=/home/sputnik

echo "---- start ----"
cd /home/dev/www/test
exec mrt

end script
```

Comment: Didn't pass the mongo url and changed last line for : `exec meteor -p domain.com:8080` also had to `chmod +x /etc/init/meteorjs.conf` and it works great :) Thx

Comment: `env HOME=/home/sputnik` if you don't like script in your script.